# await openDialog always returning false Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working on an Angular project. This example consists of an Angular dialog which opens upon a openDialog() invocation. However, I am using a method called deletePost() which calls the openDialog() method, and awaits for a result. However, the result always returns false no matter the circumstance. How should I fix this?
Here is the code:

```
async deletePost(id: string){
    let result : boolean = await this.openDialog();
    alert("result: " + result)
    if (result){
      alert("calling delete")
      this.afs.collection('products').doc(id).delete().then(() => {
        alert("Deleted Post");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('Something went wrong. Please try again');
      });
    }
  }
async openDialog(){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent);
    await dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      return result;
    });
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: is `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe` giving the boolean you are expecting? shouldn't you just be returning that? like `return dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      return result;
    });`

Comment: You can’t just async/await anything.. you are in Observable land here..